# Formstack pre-populate hidden field with javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, hidden-field

I'm trying to populate a Formstack hidden field that has an ID #filed123 (embedded on a html page using javascript) with a variable identified as tS.

Any ideas on what javascript i can use to do this? My problem is that it needs to pre-populate the field only after the DOM is ready and the form has been loaded.

Thanks in advance!

Current Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var tS = +new Date;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#field16955312').val(tS);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Assuming the field is textbox

**With Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('filed123').value = tS ;
```

**With jQuery**

```
$('#filed123').val(tS);
```

Comment: Sorry, i have corrected the question... the field i want to fill has an ID of #field123... I want to fill it with the var TS

Comment: Yes, do you want to have previous?

Comment: its just not working ,its not populating the field... i think its because the javascript function is runing before the form has loaded into the page